# Calculating total in a array

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble calculating the total numbers in an array. When a new value is added to the array the total should be updated on the view but i'm getting an undefined error.

```
var bowlingApp = angular.module('bowlingApp', []);


//Add bowling points to score
  bowlingApp.controller('bowlPoints', function ($scope){
    $scope.bowlPoints = []


    $scope.addBowlPoints = function() {

        if ($scope.bowlPoints.length  < 10) {
            $scope.bowlPoints.push($scope.enteredPoints);
        }
        else {
            alert("Thanks for playing");
        }
    };

  $scope.total = function() {
    var total = 0;
    if (scope.bowlPoints < 300) {

    for(var i=0; i < $scope.bowlPoints.length; i++) {
      total += $scope.bowlPoints[i].amount;
    }
    return total;

    };
    };
});
```

Comment: What type of object "enteredPoints" is? array? or single object like {amount:...}

Comment: Agreed, if `$scope.enteredPoints` does not have the property `amount`, then `$scope.bowlPoints[i].amount` will give you the error.  Also, what is `$scope.bowlPoints(null);` doing?

Comment: `scope.bowlPoints` should not be `$scope.bowlPoints` ?

Comment: enteredPoints is just an object

Comment: please ignore $scope.bowlPoints(null); i forgot to take that line out when I was changing things around

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the error message in a JavaScript console like in Chrome, you should be able to see exactly where the error is taking place.

An undefined error is usually the result of trying to access a property of an object that is itself undefined. For example, what erdomke said, if `$scope.enteredPoints` does not have the property amount, then `$scope.bowlPoints[i].amount` will give you an undefined error.

Hope this helps. I really recommend using a web browsers JavaScript console to debug your code, it will make things A LOT easier.

Answer (score 0):

what for is

```
if (scope.bowlPoints < 300) {
```

is it possible to get value or length of array in this indirect way without adding .length on it ?
Here [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/nuvayamokoke/8) ofcourse without angular, only javascript. Mayby it could help you ;-)